# Travelling between the UK and Norway as an Australian citizen on a standard holiday visa

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, europe, norway

I used to be a British citizen, so was accustomed to travelling pretty freely within the EU.

Later this year I'll be taking my first trip back to the UK since becoming an Australian citizen - I already have my new passport. I'll also be travelling with my Australian-born fiance.

I know we can visit the UK for up to 90 days as tourists without applying for a visa (we won't be there quite that long - about 30 days), but we are also planning to make a side-trip to Norway to visit a friend there.

I've looked at the Norwegian embassy/consulate's website, and see that we can visit Norway as tourists without a visa for a similar period as the UK.

What I can't find is explicit information about what we might need to travel from the UK to Norway and back using an Australian passport.

Because the UK and Norway are both Schengen - and they have the same visa requirements - are we free to travel between them as long as we don't remain for more than 90 days in total?

Comment: The UK is not a Schengen country. If it was, you would be correct (but I would guess there is also no problem now).

Comment: My mistake - I guess I'd assumed it was given the ease of travel into and around mainland Europe from the UK on a British passport.

Comment: Have you given up your UK passport? AFAIK, Australia allows for dual citizenship (http://www.citizenship.gov.au/current/dual_citizenship/)

Comment: I have a couple more years on my UK passport, but will likely drop it unless there are good reasons to spend money on renewing it. However, I'm also travelling with my Australian-born fiance, and have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @HorusKol once you marry your fiance, if you retain your UK nationality, you will be able to take your husband or wife to any country in the EEA (EU + a few others), except the UK, without risk of being refused entry other than for reasons of public safety, health, and policy.  For an Australian that might not be worth spending the money to keep your UK passport, or, if possible, get an endorsement in your Australian passport attesting to your UK nationality. For some nationalities who receive greater scrutiny on criteria such as finances, that could be a significant benefit.

Comment: Also, if you still have your UK passport, you are either still a UK citizen (in which case "used to be" is incorrect), or you would be breaking the law if you use it.

Comment: Indeed, travelling to the UK (and Europe) on your UK passport will make things easier all round, for you and the rest of your family.

Comment: @phoog - I just didn't know a better phrase for differentiating between my old status and my current dual citizenship status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you yourself checked and stated, you do not need a visa to visit either UK or Norway as a tourist (with an Australian passport).  As long as your stay does not exceed maximum allowed (usually 90 days), you can travel freely between the two countries.

I have heard anecdotal evidence that if you leave UK and come back "quickly", an immigration officer in the UK may decided that your short trip doesn't count as to end the first stay and start a new one.  In fact, I personally know one person that ran into this scenario (with a USA passport) - but he went to France for 1 day - and thus effectively came back to the UK on the same day as he left.  As he was still within the 90 days for the UK, it still wasn't an issue though.

Comment: So it doesn't matter that my travel into Norway isn't originating directly from Australia but from the UK?

Comment: @HorusKol: No it doesn't. In most cases the border guard who checks you into Norway won't even know which flight you arrived on. They can see in your passport you've entered the UK recently, but not how long you stayed there, given that the UK does not stamp passports on exit. (I'm not sure if the soon-to-be-reintroduced exit checks will also involve exit stamps, though).

Comment: @HorusKol if you are still a UK national, you can actually stay in the UK forever, even if you use an Australian passport to enter.  If the UK authorities try to expel you or to refuse entry, you would however need to be able to prove that you are a UK national, which is perhaps most easily done with a UK passport.